# accessing dictionary elements in a child class

Tags: python, default-value

I am trying to make a simple game I have a Character class and it has stats (dictionary) as  shown below

```
class Character():
   def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
   stats = {
    
     "Health" : 100,
     "Attack" : 1,
     "Defence": 1 }
```

and I have a Player class and it has an attack method with paramaters self, attack, defence and enemy I try to access values from stats I used

```
def attack(self, attack = self.stats.get("Attack") , defence= self.stats.get("Defence"), enemy):
    pass
```

but it says

> non-default argument follows default argument

isn't self an default arguement? and how can I fix it? (I am not very comfortable with OOP)

Comment: There is nothing about OOP or dictionaries in your question. `enemy` must have a default value - or be in the second position.

Comment: @DYZ my editor indicates self for error

Comment: Don't trust the editor, trust the error message. It tells you where the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: More likely it indicates `attack` for error.

Comment: @Putnam, `attack` is fine. `enemy` is not.

Comment: @DYZ now it says self is undefined variable I know I am a bit silly but I would be very happy if you answer it

Comment: You cannot refer to `self` in the function header because it has not been defined yet. But it is a different question.

Comment: @DYZ I was trying to ask this I want to access stats attack and defence automatically don't want to pass it every time

Comment: Hopefully, you've got an answer to your question, as asked. If you have another question ask it.

Answer (score 0):

A "default" argument is one that has a default value. In this case, your default arguments are `attack = self.stats.get("Attack")` and `defence= self.stats.get("Defence")`. A non-default argument cannot go after a default argument--default arguments must always be at the end of the arguments list.